# Effects of Sparsity of dataset in data mining

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, information-retrieval

I would like to ask how will sparsity in datasets (Multiple zero values in most dimensions) affect the search efficiency or accuracy when using Distance matrices (euclidean). I have tested such sparse datasets in ANN and FLANN and it resulted me in a very long time to search for its nearest neighbors as compared to a dense dataset. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question and without specifics it is difficult to answer. But let me give it a try.

Finding nearest neighbor in euclidean space in general requires about m*n calculations where m is the number of dimensions and n is the number of samples. You can plot the time stats for each of the datasets with m*n and see how they compare.

For sparse datasets you can also also store samples in dictionary format. In that case the average time comes to roughly k*logk*n calculations where k is the average number of nonzero elements (assuming dictionary is stored in such a way that random access time for each feature is logk. If you use something like hash tables logk part is almost unnoticeable).

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your implementations. What do you use, do you use sparse optimizations in your distance calculations, for example? Euclidean distance isn't the most sensible distance for sparse vectors, btw.

Comment: i a.m using Randomized k-d trees with priority search trees, theres no sparse optimization implemented. why does euclidean distance not work well with sparse vectors?